# Create reCAPTCHA with javascript

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

How can I have I button such that onclick it creates a reCAPTCHA?

Here is what I have:

```
<script>
function myFunc() {
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = "<div class=\"g-recaptcha\" data-sitekey=\"myspecialcodewhichisasecret\"></div>";
}
</script>
<form action="/whatever" id="form" method="post">
</form>
<button onclick="myFunc()">CLICK ME AND GET FREE RECAPTCHA</button>
```

I am using localhost, which google says should be ok. Why doesn't the recpatcha show up when I click the button?

Comment: Did you include some JavaScript from Google?

Comment: you should include google scripts after generating the recaptcha .

Comment: I doubt it will work because you are trying to use a div that would load via [automatic rendering](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#auto_render), I assume that would occur on first load of the google script, and not whenever a DOM element is added.  You will have to [explicitly render](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render) the widget, or somehow re-trigger the auto-render process.

Comment: It's right there in the docs. "Explicitly render the reCAPTCHA widget": https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render using the `grecaptcha.render()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to explicitly render the widget.

```js
function onloadCallback() {
  document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
    grecaptcha.render("form", {"sitekey": "my site key"});
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
    async defer>
</script>
<form id="form"></form>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: I wanted to have only one reCaptcha, not many. If you change that I'll accept.

Comment: No, vanilla javascript, the render method comes from google recaptcha.